# Making a dictionary out of API data

Tags: python, api, dictionary

In the first part of the project i'm doing using [NeuroMorpho.org][1] i found the ID number of neurons need. Now i want to get morphometric data for those neurons for which i want to download certain morphometric data from and save them in a dictionary. I used the following code:

```
n = [100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464,100,101,1016,1019,102,1020,1023,1026,1028,1029,103,1030,1034,1035,104,1040,108828,108829,108830,108831,108838,108839,108840,108841,111008,111009,111010,111011,111012,111013,111014,111015,111016,111017,111018,111019,111020,111021,111022,111023,111024,111025,111026,111027,111028,112460,112461,112462,112463,112464]
rat_morphometry = []
for i in n:
    url = "http://neuromorpho.org/api//morphometry/id/" + str(i)
    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data = response.json()
    rat_morphometry.append(json_data)
    print (rat_morphometry)
```

All of the data gets printed (takes time).

I tried just to get surface data for the begining and tried this:

```
df_dict = {
'Surface': list()}
for row in rat_morphometry:
    df_dict['Surface'].append(str(row['surface']))
rat_morphometry_df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
print(rat_morphometry)
```

However, i'm not getting anything in the form of a dataframe. Basically, i'm gettting the same output as in the first section. Additionally, now i'm only getting info for like 8 neurons. I'm afraid it is due to NeuroMorpho limitations concerning the morphometric data (they state: *The number of the neuron measurements listed per page. Please note that the maximum size allowed per page is 500.*). The problem is the first section doesn't show me the number of pages through which i can loop and get the info for all neurons.

Tnx in advance if anyone can help!

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to achieve? The list `rat_morphometry` contains all the data fetched from that link. Transforming/filtering it should be easy. An example would help clarify what your goal is.

Comment: I want to get nicely organized data which i will later use for statistical analysis. Variables organized in columns i.e. NeuronID (1st column), Surface (2nd column),... followed by all other morphometric data, while the neuron data would be placed in rows.

Comment: Have you tried `df = pd.DataFrame(rat_morphometry)`? It works for me :)

Comment: ...Beginers mistake. Did print (rat_morphometry) instead of print (rat_morphometry_df)...
Tnx for poiting it out!